# SPRINTF in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I have an auto-generated file each day that gets called by a shell script. 
But, the problem I'm facing is that the auto-generated file has a form of:

```
FILE_MM_DD.dat
```

... where MM and DD are 2-digit month and day-of-the-month strings.

I did some research and banged it at on my own, but I don't know how to create these custom strings using only shell scripting.

To be clear, I am aware of the DATE function in Bash, but what I'm looking for is the equivalent of the SPRINTF function in C.

Comment: Also, my spec requires that I generate strings like FILE_12_1.dat instead of FILE_12_01.dat where required.

Comment: Correct, the DD is not part of my spec, but just a shortcut for explaining things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In Bash:

```
var=$(printf 'FILE=_%s_%s.dat' "$val1" "$val2")
```

or, the equivalent, and closer to `sprintf`:

```
printf -v var 'FILE=_%s_%s.dat' "$val1" "$val2"
```

If your variables contain decimal values with leading zeros, you can remove the leading zeros:

```
val1=008; val2=02
var=$(printf 'FILE=_%d_%d.dat' $((10#$val1)) $((10#$val2)))
```

or

```
printf -v var 'FILE=_%d_%d.dat' $((10#$val1)) $((10#$val2))
```

The `$((10#$val1))` coerces the value into base 10 so the `%d` in the format specification doesn't think that "08" is an invalid octal value.

If you're using `date` (at least for GNU `date`), you can omit the leading zeros like this:

```
date '+FILE_%-m_%-d.dat'
```

For completeness, if you want to *add* leading zeros, padded to a certain width:

```
val1=8; val2=2
printf -v var 'FILE=_%04d_%06d.dat' "$val1" "$val2"
```

or with dynamic widths:

```
val1=8; val2=2
width1=4; width2=6
printf -v var 'FILE=_%0*d_%0*d.dat' "$width1" "$val1" "$width2" "$val2"
```

Adding leading zeros is useful for creating values that sort easily and align neatly in columns.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. This is the closest solution I've seen so far. And by closest, I mean perfect :)

Comment: Quotes! `"$var1"`, `"$var2"`, etc. Even knowing that the values are numeric -- what if there are digits in IFS?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Quotes added. Normally, I have a supervisory function that detects whether `IFS` contains digits or the existence of other undesired conditions and, if so, `dd`'s zeroes to all reachable filesystems. ;-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and Dennis Thank you for finding and fixing issues, even on old answers.

Answer (score 9):

Why not using the printf program from coreutils?

```
$ printf "FILE_%02d_%02d.dat" 1 2
FILE_01_02.dat
```

Comment: Thank you, halo. I also just found this option:

    $ date "+FILE_%m_%d"
    FILE_12_07

Comment: To be clear, what I'd like is a truncation of leading zeros, but I think I can figure that out from the PRINTF man page.

Comment: What do you mean by "truncation of leading zeros"? Please explain and will offer my skills at printf or regex magic if necessary;-) If you find the solution on your own, please post. I'd be interested in understanding what you actually needed.

Comment: `printf(1)` works exactly like `printf(3)`, so if you're having trouble with your format then you'd have trouble in C, too. Theoretically the bash builtin might be different, but I doubt it.

Comment: `printf` is actually also a Bash builtin.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sprintf() { local stdin; read -d '' -u 0 stdin; printf "$@" "$stdin"; }
```

Example:

```
$ echo bar | sprintf "foo %s"
foo bar
```