# How to display number to two decimal places in bash function

Tags: linux, bash

How should I take a number that is in hundreths of seconds and display it in seconds to two decimal places? Psuedo code to follow the dTime function I am not sure about but you'll get what I'm aiming for I think.

```
function time {
    echo "$(date +%N)/10000000"
}

function dTime {
    echo "($1/100).(${$1:${#1}-3:${#1}-1})"
}

T=$time
sleep 2
T=$dTime T
```

Comment: bash only performs integer arithmetic. Your question is somewhat misleading as you're asking about displaying a number to two decimal places, and the code you show clearly performs floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Use [printf][1] and piggyback on long-tested code.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377871/sprintf-in-shell-scripting

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Bash has a printf function built in:

```
printf "%0.2f\n" $T
```

Comment: Be aware that printf depends on locales settings ! In Fr for example, ',' is used in locale for float separation, not '.'. So in Fr,
    printf "%0.2f\n" 26.600
will return an error (the number must be expressed as "26,600")

Answer (score 11):

Below can be done for 2 decimal precision ,

```
echo $T | bc -l | xargs printf "%.2f"
```

Answer (score 7):

The following divides the output of `date +%N` by `1000000000`, rounds the result to two decimal places and assigns the result to the variable `T`.

```
printf -v T "%.2f" $(bc -l <<< "$(date +%N)/1000000000")
```

If you just want to print the stuff,

```
bc <<< "scale=2; $(date +%N)/1000000000"
```

If you don't like `bc` and want to use `dc` (which is a bit lighter and much funnier to use as it's reverse polish),

```
dc <<< "2 k $(date +%N) 1000000000 / p"
```

Notice the difference, with `printf` you'll have the leading `0`, not with `bc` and `dc`. There's another difference between `printf` and `bc` (or `dc`): `printf` rounds to the nearest number to two decimal places, whereas `bc` (or `dc`) rounds correct to two decimal places. If you want this latter behavior and assign to a variable `T` the result, you can use, e.g.,

```
T=$(dc <<< "2 k $(date +%N) 1000000000 / p")
```

or, if you also want the leading `0`:

```
T=0.$(dc <<< "2 k $(date +%N) 1000000000 / p")
```

Answer (score 1):

"bc" and "dc" both truncate rather than round, so nowadays I prefer Perl

If "N" has your number of hundreths of seconds in it then:

```
$ perl -e "printf('%.2f', $N/100)"
```

I was never a Perl supporter but it is now ubiquitous and I have finally been swayed to using it instead of sed/awk etc.